# Install Windows 10 appxbundle on windows 10 mobile

Tags: c#, deployment, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, sideloading

I have created windows 10 universal app. I am able to install it on desktop using powershell, but not able to install on phone.

In W10 we can directly sideload apps by enabling setting for the same.

As far I found two ways to install on phone:
1) Install certificate generated while package generation and **directly click** on appxbundle (say through Files) and app will be installed in less than 30 secs.
2) Install W10 SDK, then using **WinAppDeployCmd tool** we can deploy it to phone.

I am finding first way simple, but nothing happens on click of install, which appears after click on appxbundle.

Anyone suffered from this, any OS version issue or any other things.

Your suggestions are welcome
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found that distributing a release version of the appxbundle worked. Since we need QA to have access to builds, we figured using the command line tool didn't seem efficient. Still looking into why debug doesn't work though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11422187)

Comment: How is that not an answer? I had the same issue and found that a release build worked where debug builds don't?

Answer (score 0):

No error statement makes this difficult.
I am going to suggest that you have an unregistered COM item. But it appears that you have nothing happening.

So check your package appmanifest, "view with code", check for any odd additions.

If you do get an error check the GUID in the registry if you get one.

Let me know if this answered your question, there are number of these on the web without a solution.

Comment: Got this worked with windows 10 installed and command line tool. I had to install Latest mobile image.